# How to route IPv6 traffic on Windows through Linux TOR gateway?

Tags: linux, windows, ipv6, tor, gateway

I have a Debian VM set up running TOR to use as a gateway to connect other machines to to anonymize their traffic. The `torrc` file on the VM is configured like this:

```
Log notice file /var/log/tor/notices.log
VirtualAddrNetwork 10.192.0.0/10
AutomapHostSuffixes .onion,.exit
AutomapHostsOnResolve 1
TransPort 9040
TransListenAddress 192.168.1.135
DNSPort 53
DNSListenAddress 192.168.1.135
```

And my iptables are setup as:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh     redir ports 22
REDIRECT   udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain redir ports 53
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN redir ports 9040

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Now, on any machine I want to anonymize, I change its default gateway and DNS to 192.168.1.135, and most of my traffic goes through TOR.

However, when I check a site that gives my IPv6 address, it still shows my real IPv6, so it appears any connections using IPv6 are not protected.

What do I need to do to have IPv6 routed through the same gateway? Do I just need to change my IPv6 Default Gateway in Windows to the IPv6 address of the Gateway VM, or is there more configuration needed to do on the Gateway side?

Comment: "_However, when I check a site that gives my IPv6 address, it still shows my real IPv6, so it appears any connections using IPv6 are not protected._" I don't understand what that means. Just because IPv6 uses global addressing doesn't mean it isn't protected by a firewall. If your gateway includes an IPv6 firewall you should be fine.

Comment: Because it isn't anonymizing my traffic.

Comment: The whole point of IPv6 is that it restores the end-to-end connectivity lost by the need for NAT in IPv4 because of the address shortage. The goal is that all devices will use global addresses, fixing the problems caused by NAT. Using the proprietary NAT for IPv6 (there is no official NAT RFC for IPv6, the way there is for IPv4) breaks some IPv6 features.

Comment: Im trying to route all my activity through the TOR network though, and my actual IPv6 address is leaking.

Comment: That is the point of IPv6. Each end-point is uniquely defined by an assigned global IPv6 address, and traffic can be identified. If you obfuscate an IPv6 address, it breaks features of IPv6. This was the original premise of IP, and it was broken in IPv4. IPv6 aims to restore this end-to-end connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `ip6tables` for actions regarding IPv6

It's also worth noting that IPv6 addresses need to be put in `[]` for `TransListenAddress`, eg: `TransListenAddress [::1]`